# How to receive thread callbacks in Python

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

This may have been asked before, but I couldn't find what I am looking for. I have background thread launched from main UI thread (TKinter), and I would like it to send status updates to UI. I appreciate some code or pseudo or links that show how this can be done in python.

pseudo code:
    //test.py

```
def __init__(self, parent):
#Button
self.submit_button = Button(self,
                text="launch_tasks",
                command=self.launch_tasks).pack()
#label
self.label = Label(master, text="Hello, world!")
self.label.pack()

def launch_tasks(self)
   t = Thread(target=self.process_tasks)
   t.start()

def process_tasks(self):
    cnt = getJobs(self);
    self.label = cnt   # I like to update label here
    for(job in jobs):
      process(job)
      self.label = 'processing' + job # I like to update label 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

### Complement Tkinter with a messaging-layer with an event-routing added

While a Tkinter/**`.mainloop()`** is a self-contained Model-Visual-Controller system, you may extend it's functionality in a thread-safe, non-blocking mode with an added complementary ( inter-process / any-to-any ) Messaging Layer of your own and equip it's localhost/self actors with a Tkinter-based event-routing mechanism to integrate with the `.mainloop()`

```
################################################ SETUP EVENT-ROUTING Injector

self.aSigFromZMQ = "<<aVirtualEventSignalledFromZMQ_LAYER>>"

self.bind( self.aSigFromZMQ, anEventHANDLER )
#   |
#   .bind <<virtual_EventNAME>> altogether with <anEventHANDLER>-call


################################################ Context-fully TRIGGER Injector

self.event_generate( self.aSigFromZMQ, aSigContextDICT )
#   |
#   .event_generate( <eventNameId>, **args )  #   triggers <eventNameId>
#                                             # + passes **args, that allows
#                                             #          to set <keyword>=<value> pairs for Event-fields,
#                                             #          that are passed to anEventHANDLER via <Event>-object ...
```

For illustration and for click-through link to the genuine book from one of the fathers of the state-of-art, incredibly fast, smart & scaleable inter-process messaging system for many-to-many messaging **( incl. inter-thread signalling once based on this )** kindly ref. >>> 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26559710/3666197

---

[image]

### Thread-to-Thread signalling ( Callbacks Unlimited )